# The string in the struct cannot be output after being put into the vector --- a problem

Tags: c++

I defined a string class called "atom" in struct. Like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include "Sab.h"


using namespace std;


struct STO
{
string atom;
int atomNo;
int BNoba;
int SNoba;
int coatomNo;
int baatomNo;
int px;
int py;
int pz;
double x=0.0;
double y=0.0;
double z=0.0;
};
```

then I defined a vector and single struct to get input data.

```
int main()
{
......
ifstream inco("nh3.gjf");
if(!inco)
{
cout << "can't open this file!" << endl;
exit( 1 );
}
........
vector<STO> sto;
STO stotemp;
......
while ( sscanf( StrLine.c_str(), " %[a-zA-Z] %lf%lf%lf", stotemp.atom.c_str(), &(stotemp.x), &(stotemp.y), &(stotemp.z)) == 4 )
......
cout << stotemp.atom.c_str() << " " <<stotemp.coatomNo<<" "<< stotemp.atom << " " << stotemp.x << " " << stotemp.y << " " << stotemp.z << endl;
```

Everyting is ok so far. The output of stotemp.atom.c_str() is normal. But when I put stotemp into the vector sto, something happened.

```
sto.push_back(stotemp);
......
cout << tempc.c_str()<< " "<< sto[i].atom.c_str() << endl;
```

I can't get any out put from sto[i].atom.c_str(), but the other members in sto[i] is normal.
Anyone tell me how to fix it? thanks a lot!
Complete code (didn't finished)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include "Sab.h"


using namespace std;


struct STO
{
string atom;
int atomNo;
int BNoba;
int SNoba;
int coatomNo;
int baatomNo;
int px;
int py;
int pz;
double x=0.0;
double y=0.0;
double z=0.0;
};


int main()
{
inti, j, k, l, m , sums,sump, p, q, s1, s2, s3, s4,nse, stons,ns,np, npe,stonp, nd, nc, na, charge, spin, **zetas, **zetap, *elec, *eleb ,tempi,*han;
double**co, **basa, **basc, **bapa, **bapc, tempd ,hh ,kk ,V_nn ,Escf ,**C_ij ,**S_ij ,**T_ij ,**H_ij ,**F_ij , **P_ij;
stringStrLine, tempc;
charZele[119][3] = { "0", "H", "He", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne" };
ifstream inco("nh3.gjf");
if(!inco)
{
cout << "can't open this file!" << endl;
exit( 1 );
}
ifstream inba("3-21g.TXT");
if(!inba)
{
cout << "can't open this file!" << endl;
exit( 1 );
}
nc=0;
while(!inco.eof())
{
getline(inco,StrLine);
if ( sscanf( StrLine.c_str(), "%d%d", &charge, &spin ) == 2 )
{
//cout << StrLine << endl;
nc = 0;
while (!inco.eof())
{
getline(inco,StrLine);
nc++;
}
break;
}
}
na = 0;
tempi = 0;
while ( !inba.eof() )
{
getline(inba,StrLine);
if ( sscanf( StrLine.c_str(), "%[a-zA-Z] %d ",tempc.c_str() , &tempi ) == 2 && tempi == 0 )
{
na++;
}
}
inba.clear();
inba.seekg(0,inba.beg);
inco.seekg(0,inco.beg);
vector<STO> sto;
STO stotemp;
i = 1;
while ( !inco.eof() )
{
getline(inco,StrLine);
if ( sscanf( StrLine.c_str(), "%d%d", &charge, &spin ) == 2 )
{
i = 1;
getline(inco,StrLine);
while ( sscanf( StrLine.c_str(), " %[a-zA-Z] %lf%lf%lf", stotemp.atom.c_str(), &(stotemp.x), &(stotemp.y), &(stotemp.z)) == 4 )
{
stotemp.x=stotemp.x/0.5291772083;
stotemp.y=stotemp.y/0.5291772083;
stotemp.z=stotemp.z/0.5291772083;
for ( j = 1; j <= 118; j++ )
{
if ( strcmp( stotemp.atom.c_str(), Zele[j] ) == 0 )
{
stotemp.atomNo = j;
stotemp.coatomNo= i;
cout << stotemp.atom.c_str() << " " <<stotemp.coatomNo<<" "<< stotemp.atom << " " << stotemp.x << " " << stotemp.y << " " << stotemp.z << endl;
sto.push_back(stotemp);
i++;
break;
}
}
if(inco.eof())
break;
else
getline(inco,StrLine);
}
}
}
while ( !inba.eof() )
{
getline(inba,StrLine);
if ( sscanf( StrLine.c_str(), "%[a-zA-Z] 0 ", tempc.c_str() ) == 1 )
{
for ( i =0; i <= nc-1; i++ )
{
for(j=0;j<=na-1;j++)
{
stotemp=sto[i];
cout << tempc.c_str()<< " "<< sto[i].atom << endl;
system("pause");
if ( strcmp( tempc.c_str(), stotemp.atom.c_str() ) == 0 )
{


sto[i].baatomNo = j+1;
cout << sto[i].atomNo <<sto[i].baatomNo << endl;
system("pause");
break;
}
}
}
}
}
inba.seekg(0,inba.beg);
V_nn=0.0;
for ( i = 0; i <= nc-1; i++ )
{
for ( j = i+1; j <= nc-1; j++ )
{
V_nn+=(sto[i].atomNo*sto[j].atomNo)/norm2(sto[i].x,sto[i].y, sto[i].z ,sto[j].x,sto[j].y, sto[j].z );
}
}
cout << "coordinate and distance are expressed by Bhor" << endl;
cout << fixed<<setprecision(6) <<V_nn << endl;
inco.seekg(0,inco.beg);
system("pause");
/* ns= 0;
np= 0;
nse= 0;
npe= 0;
tempi=0;
stons = 0;
stonp = 0;
for(i=0 ; i<= nc-1 ; i++)
{
for ( j = 0; j <= na-1; j++ )
{
while ( !inba.eof())
{
getline( inba,StrLine );
if ( strstr( StrLine.c_str(), "****" ) != NULL )
{
break;
}
if ( sscanf( StrLine.c_str(), "S %d %*lf", &j ) == 1 )
{
ns+= j; 
nse+= j; 
stons += 1; 
}
if ( sscanf( StrLine.c_str(), "SP %d %*lf", &j ) == 1 )
{
ns= ns + j;
np= np + j;
nse+= j;
npe+= j;
stons+= 1;
stonp+= 3; 
}
}
}
}*/
}
```

nh3.gjf:

```
%chk=D:\LSZ\tf\NH3\nh3.chk
# hf/3-21g geom=connectivity


Title Card Required


0 1
N 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
H 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
H 0.94280915 0.00000000 -0.33333304
H -0.47140478 -0.81649655 -0.33333304
```

3-21g.TXT:

```
H     0 
S   2   1.00
      5.4471780              0.1562850        
      0.8245470              0.9046910        
S   1   1.00
      0.1831920              1.0000000        
****
N     0 
S   3   1.00
    242.7660000              0.0598657        
     36.4851000              0.3529550        
      7.8144900              0.7065130        
SP   2   1.00
      5.4252200             -0.4133010              0.2379720        
      1.1491500              1.2244200              0.8589530        
SP   1   1.00
      0.2832050              1.0000000              1.0000000        
****
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Oh! I forgot the Sab! sorry!
Sab.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define pai 3.1415927

double norm2(double xx1,double yy1,double zz1,double xx2,double yy2,double zz2)
{
    double norm;
    norm=sqrt(pow(xx2-xx1,2)+pow(yy2-yy1,2)+pow(zz2-zz1,2));
    return norm;
}
```

and Sab.h

```
#ifndef SAB_H_INCLUDED
#define SAB_H_INCLUDED
double norm2(double xx1,double yy1,double zz1,double xx2,double yy2,double zz2);


#endif // SAB_H_INCLUDED
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: You can't read into a `string` using `c_str()` or any form of `scanf` function.

Comment: But actully we can. I did get the output from `stotemp.atom.c_str()` form `sscanf`. the problem is when I put `stotemp` into the vector `sto`, I can't get output from `sto[i].atom.c_str()`
@1201ProgramAlarm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not read into `stotemp.c_str()` because that is of type `const char *`, thus you should not modify its content. My compiler (g++) gives a warning about that.

Your code *seems* to work because a `std::string` object contains an internal buffer that holds the actual string data and also a field that specifies the size of the string. A call to `c_str()` returns a pointer to this buffer. If you use the `std::string` default constructor then this internal buffer is created with a certain size. In my case the default initial buffer size is 15. `c_str()` returns this buffer. So you can safely read up to 15 characters into that buffer. If you then print that buffer immediately, it will show the correct string. However, with your `scanf` operation you do *not* update the length field of the string object. So the object still thinks that the string has length 0, so it will only copy a string of length 0 when copying the structure into the vector.

As you can see, you are just misusing the internal buffer of a `std::string` instance and it is pure luck that this does create problems. As soon as the string you read will be longer than the initial buffer size of a `std::string` you will write into bad memory locations and your program will probably crash.

In order to scan those 4 fields from `StrLine` you could do something like this:

```
  std::stringstream s(StrLine);
  while (s >> stotemp.atom >> stotemp.x >> stotemp.y >> stotemp.z) {
    std::cout << stotemp.atom << ", " << stotemp.x << ", "
              << stotemp.y << ", " << stotemp.z << std::endl;
  }
```

or explicitly handle the beginning of the string and the use `sscanf` for the rest:

```
  char const *line = StrLine.c_str();
  while (isspace(*line)) ++line; // Skip leading whitespace
  char const *end = line;
  while (isalpha(*end)) ++end; // Find first non-alpha charachter
  stotemp.atom = std::string(line, end); // capcture string
  sscanf(end, "%lf %lf %lf", &stotemp.x, &stotemp.y, &stotemp.z);
  std::cout << stotemp.atom << ", " << stotemp.x << ", "
            << stotemp.y << ", " << stotemp.z << std::endl;
  return 0;
```

That would give you more control about what characters you want to accept for `atom`.

Comment: (^_^)Thanks a lot.  (^_^)